# How to copy data from a numpy array to another

Tags: python, numpy

What is the fastest way to copy data from array b to array a, without modifying the address of array a. I need this because an external library (PyFFTW) uses a pointer to my array that cannot change.

For example:

```
a = numpy.empty(n, dtype=complex)
for i in xrange(a.size):
  a[i] = b[i]
```

It is possible to do it without a loop?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I believe

```
a = numpy.empty_like(b)
a[:] = b
```

will copy the values quickly. As Funsi mentions, recent versions of numpy also have the `copyto` function.

Comment: +1. But wouldn't [numpy.empty](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html) be substantially fast than [numpy.zeros](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html)?

Comment: I wonder what is the difference between `a[:] = b` and `a = b` ?

Comment: @M.ElSaka `a = b` merely creates a new reference to `b`. `a[:] = b` means "set all elements of `a` equal to those of `b`". The difference is important because numpy arrays are mutable types.

Comment: @mg007 I ran some tests, which showed `empty()` is about 10% faster than `zeros()`. Surprisingly `empty_like()` is even faster. `copyto(a,b)` is faster than the array syntax `a[:] = b`. See https://gist.github.com/bhawkins/5095558

Comment: @Brian Hawkins is right. For when to use `np.copyto(a, b)` and when `a = b.astype(b.dtype)` for a speed improvement, see the answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33672015/3703716

Comment: `b = a.copy()` is __MUCH__ more simple and faster

Comment: @MarcoSulla `b=a.copy()` creates a new array.  We need to modify an existing object, not create a new one.  (The OP requires a constant memory address.)

Comment: If you do `a = numpy.empty_like (b)`, you're creating a new array: `numpy.empty_like [...] Return a new array with the same shape and type as a given array` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.empty_like.html

Comment: Furthermore, I would add that `a[:] = b` is **not** a deep copy, as stated.

Comment: @MarcoSulla You're correct but missing the point. The problem to solve is "given an array `a` how do I set its data equal to the data of another array `b`?"  The `empty_like` is incidental, just a way to accomplish the initial allocation of `a`.  Maybe I should remove it from the answer.  The requirement is to be able to call a C library that needs a constant memory address (part of the `a` object), but one might want to update the memory contents.  The OP is probably initializing an FFTW object using `a` and wants to compute several transforms with different data.

Comment: _"surprisingly `empty_like()` is even faster"_  => the `empty_like()`  function does _not_ initialize the returned array; "to do that use `zeros_like()` or `ones_like()` instead. It may be marginally faster than the functions that do set the array values."   https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty_like.html#numpy.empty_like

Comment: @michael_n I was surprised `empty_like` is so much faster than `empty`, especially since `zeros_like` is slower than `zeros`. BTW I just re-ran my benchmark (now updated), and the difference between `copyto(a,b)` and `a[:] = b` seems to have evaporated. https://gist.github.com/bhawkins/5095558

Comment: If your arrays need to be different data types, copyto will not work, but the array slice syntax will work.

Comment: Evidence that this is not a deep copy (thanks @MarcoSulla for pointing out): `a = np.array([{"k":1}]);  b = np.array([{"k":2}]);  a[:] = b;  a[0]['k'] = 9;  print(b)`

Comment: @pianoJames Thanks for the example. I hadn't considered the `dtype=object` case and will edit the answer.

Answer (score 31):

NumPy version 1.7 has the `numpy.copyto` function that does what you are looking for:

> numpy.copyto(dst, src)
>
> Copies values from one array to another, broadcasting as necessary.

See:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copyto.html

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I get `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'copyto'`

Answer (score 23):

```
a = numpy.array(b)
```

is even faster than the suggested solutions up to numpy v1.6 and makes a copy of the array as well. I could however not test it against copyto(a,b), since I don't have the most recent version of numpy.

Comment: This is a great way to copy an array, but it creates a new object. The OP needs to know how to quickly assign values to an array that's already been created.

Answer (score 19):

To answer your question, I played with some variants and profiled them.

Conclusion: to copy data from a numpy array to another use one of the built-in numpy functions [`numpy.array(src)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) or [`numpy.copyto(dst, src)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copyto.html) wherever possible.

**Update 2022-05**: re-test with numpy v1.22 and CPython v3.9 showed that [`src.astype(...)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html?highlight=astype#numpy.ndarray.astype) is currently fastest almost consistently on my system. So, better run the provided code snipped yourself to get numbers for your specific setup.

(But always choose `numpy.copyto(dst, src)` if `dst`'s memory is already allocated, to reuse the memory. See profiling at the end of the post.)

**profiling setup**

```
import timeit
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display
    
def profile_this(methods, setup='', niter=10 ** 4, p_globals=None, **kwargs):
    if p_globals is not None:
        print('globals: {0}, tested {1:.0e} times'.format(p_globals, niter))
    timings = np.array([timeit.timeit(method, setup=setup, number=niter,
                                      globals=p_globals, **kwargs) for 
                        method in methods])
    ranking = np.argsort(timings)
    timings = np.array(timings)[ranking]
    methods = np.array(methods)[ranking]
    speedups = np.amax(timings) / timings

    # pd.set_option('html', False)
    data = {'time (s)': timings,
            'speedup': ['{:.2f}x'.format(s) if s != 1 else '' for s in speedups],
            'methods': methods}
    data_frame = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['time (s)', 'speedup', 'methods'])

    display(data_frame)
    print()
```

**profiling code**

```
setup = '''import numpy as np; x = np.random.random(n)'''
methods = (
    '''y = np.zeros(n, dtype=x.dtype); y[:] = x''',
    '''y = np.zeros_like(x); y[:] = x''',
    '''y = np.empty(n, dtype=x.dtype); y[:] = x''',
    '''y = np.empty_like(x); y[:] = x''',
    '''y = np.copy(x)''',
    '''y = x.astype(x.dtype)''',
    '''y = 1*x''',
    '''y = np.empty_like(x); np.copyto(y, x)''',
    '''y = np.empty_like(x); np.copyto(y, x, casting='no')''',
    '''y = np.empty(n)\nfor i in range(x.size):\n\ty[i] = x[i]'''
)

for n, it in ((2, 6), (3, 6), (3.8, 6), (4, 6), (5, 5), (6, 4.5)):
    profile_this(methods[:-1:] if n > 2 else methods, setup, 
                 niter=int(10 ** it), p_globals={'n': int(10 ** n)})
```

**results** for Windows 7 on Intel i7 CPU, CPython v3.5.0, numpy v1.10.1.

```js
globals: {'n': 100}, tested 1e+06 times

     time (s) speedup                                            methods
0    0.386908  33.76x                                    y = np.array(x)
1    0.496475  26.31x                              y = x.astype(x.dtype)
2    0.567027  23.03x              y = np.empty_like(x); np.copyto(y, x)
3    0.666129  19.61x                     y = np.empty_like(x); y[:] = x
4    0.967086  13.51x                                            y = 1*x
5    1.067240  12.24x  y = np.empty_like(x); np.copyto(y, x, casting=...
6    1.235198  10.57x                                     y = np.copy(x)
7    1.624535   8.04x           y = np.zeros(n, dtype=x.dtype); y[:] = x
8    1.626120   8.03x           y = np.empty(n, dtype=x.dtype); y[:] = x
9    3.569372   3.66x                     y = np.zeros_like(x); y[:] = x
10  13.061154          y = np.empty(n)\nfor i in range(x.size):\n\ty[...


globals: {'n': 1000}, tested 1e+06 times

   time (s) speedup                                            methods
0  0.666237   6.10x                              y = x.astype(x.dtype)
1  0.740594   5.49x              y = np.empty_like(x); np.copyto(y, x)
2  0.755246   5.39x                                    y = np.array(x)
3  1.043631   3.90x                     y = np.empty_like(x); y[:] = x
4  1.398793   2.91x                                            y = 1*x
5  1.434299   2.84x  y = np.empty_like(x); np.copyto(y, x, casting=...
6  1.544769   2.63x                                     y = np.copy(x)
7  1.873119   2.17x           y = np.empty(n, dtype=x.dtype); y[:] = x
8  2.355593   1.73x           y = np.zeros(n, dtype=x.dtype); y[:] = x
9  4.067133                             y = np.zeros_like(x); y[:] = x


globals: {'n': 6309}, tested 1e+06 times

   time (s) speedup                                            methods
0  2.338428   3.05x                                    y = np.array(x)
1  2.466636   2.89x                              y = x.astype(x.dtype)
2  2.561535   2.78x              y = np.empty_like(x); np.copyto(y, x)
3  2.603601   2.74x                     y = np.empty_like(x); y[:] = x
4  3.005610   2.37x  y = np.empty_like(x); np.copyto(y, x, casting=...
5  3.215863   2.22x                                     y = np.copy(x)
6  3.249763   2.19x                                            y = 1*x
7  3.661599   1.95x           y = np.empty(n, dtype=x.dtype); y[:] = x
8  6.344077   1.12x           y = np.zeros(n, dtype=x.dtype); y[:] = x
9  7.133050                             y = np.zeros_like(x); y[:] = x


globals: {'n': 10000}, tested 1e+06 times

   time (s) speedup                                            methods
0  3.421806   2.82x                                    y = np.array(x)
1  3.569501   2.71x                              y = x.astype(x.dtype)
2  3.618747   2.67x              y = np.empty_like(x); np.copyto(y, x)
3  3.708604   2.61x                     y = np.empty_like(x); y[:] = x
4  4.150505   2.33x  y = np.empty_like(x); np.copyto(y, x, casting=...
5  4.402126   2.19x                                     y = np.copy(x)
6  4.917966   1.96x           y = np.empty(n, dtype=x.dtype); y[:] = x
7  4.941269   1.96x                                            y = 1*x
8  8.925884   1.08x           y = np.zeros(n, dtype=x.dtype); y[:] = x
9  9.661437                             y = np.zeros_like(x); y[:] = x


globals: {'n': 100000}, tested 1e+05 times

    time (s) speedup                                            methods
0   3.858588   2.63x                              y = x.astype(x.dtype)
1   3.873989   2.62x                                    y = np.array(x)
2   3.896584   2.60x              y = np.empty_like(x); np.copyto(y, x)
3   3.919729   2.58x  y = np.empty_like(x); np.copyto(y, x, casting=...
4   3.948563   2.57x                     y = np.empty_like(x); y[:] = x
5   4.000521   2.53x                                     y = np.copy(x)
6   4.087255   2.48x           y = np.empty(n, dtype=x.dtype); y[:] = x
7   4.803606   2.11x                                            y = 1*x
8   6.723291   1.51x                     y = np.zeros_like(x); y[:] = x
9  10.131983                   y = np.zeros(n, dtype=x.dtype); y[:] = x


globals: {'n': 1000000}, tested 3e+04 times

     time (s) speedup                                            methods
0   85.625484   1.24x                     y = np.empty_like(x); y[:] = x
1   85.693316   1.24x              y = np.empty_like(x); np.copyto(y, x)
2   85.790064   1.24x  y = np.empty_like(x); np.copyto(y, x, casting=...
3   86.342230   1.23x           y = np.empty(n, dtype=x.dtype); y[:] = x
4   86.954862   1.22x           y = np.zeros(n, dtype=x.dtype); y[:] = x
5   89.503368   1.18x                                    y = np.array(x)
6   91.986177   1.15x                                            y = 1*x
7   95.216021   1.11x                                     y = np.copy(x)
8  100.524358   1.05x                              y = x.astype(x.dtype)
9  106.045746                             y = np.zeros_like(x); y[:] = x
```

---

Also, see results for a variant of the profiling where the destination's memory is already **pre-allocated** during value copying, since `y = np.empty_like(x)` is part of the setup:

```js
globals: {'n': 100}, tested 1e+06 times

   time (s) speedup                        methods
0  0.328492   2.33x                np.copyto(y, x)
1  0.384043   1.99x                y = np.array(x)
2  0.405529   1.89x                       y[:] = x
3  0.764625          np.copyto(y, x, casting='no')


globals: {'n': 1000}, tested 1e+06 times

   time (s) speedup                        methods
0  0.453094   1.95x                np.copyto(y, x)
1  0.537594   1.64x                       y[:] = x
2  0.770695   1.15x                y = np.array(x)
3  0.884261          np.copyto(y, x, casting='no')


globals: {'n': 6309}, tested 1e+06 times

   time (s) speedup                        methods
0  2.125426   1.20x                np.copyto(y, x)
1  2.182111   1.17x                       y[:] = x
2  2.364018   1.08x                y = np.array(x)
3  2.553323          np.copyto(y, x, casting='no')


globals: {'n': 10000}, tested 1e+06 times

   time (s) speedup                        methods
0  3.196402   1.13x                np.copyto(y, x)
1  3.523396   1.02x                       y[:] = x
2  3.531007   1.02x                y = np.array(x)
3  3.597598          np.copyto(y, x, casting='no')


globals: {'n': 100000}, tested 1e+05 times

   time (s) speedup                        methods
0  3.862123   1.01x                np.copyto(y, x)
1  3.863693   1.01x                y = np.array(x)
2  3.873194   1.01x                       y[:] = x
3  3.909018          np.copyto(y, x, casting='no')
```

Comment: Also `x.copy()` is as fast as `np.array(x)` and I like the syntax much more: `$ python3 -m timeit -s "import numpy as np; x = np.random.random((100, 100))" "x.copy()"` - `100000 loops, best of 3: 4.7 usec per loop`. I have similar results for `np.array(x)`. Tested on Linux with an i5-4210U and numpy 1.10.4

Comment: Yes Marco, it is rather a matter of personal taste. But note that `np.copy` is more forgiving: `np.copy(False)`, `np.copy(None)` still work, while `a = None; a.copy()` throws `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'`. Also, we are more precise on declaring what we want to happen in this line of code using the function instead of the method syntax.

Comment: Well, the fact `np.copy(None)` does not throw an error is really unpythonic. One reason more to use `a.copy()` :)

Comment: I just ran these benchmarks with Python 2.7.12, NumPy 1.11.2 and find that `y[:] = x` is now marginally faster than `copyto(y, x)`. Code and output at https://gist.github.com/bhawkins/7cdbd5b9372cb798e34e21f92279d2dc

Answer (score 10):

you can easy use:

```
b = 1*a
```

this is the fastest way, but also have some problems. If you don't define directly the `dtype` of `a` and also doesn't check the `dtype` of `b` you can get into trouble. For example:

```
a = np.arange(10)        # dtype = int64
b = 1*a                  # dtype = int64

a = np.arange(10.)       # dtype = float64
b = 1*a                  # dtype = float64

a = np.arange(10)        # dtype = int64
b = 1. * a               # dtype = float64
```

I hope, I could make the point clear. Sometimes you will have a data type change with just one little operation.

Comment: No. Doing so creates a new array. It is equivalent to b = a.copy().

Comment: sorry, but I don't get you. What do you mean with create a new array? All the other methods which are presented here have the same behavior. `a = numpy.zeros(len(b))` or `a = numpy.empty(n,dtype=complex)` will also create a new array.

Comment: Suppose you have a = numpy.empty(1000) . Now, you need to fill a with data, without changing its address in memory. If you do a[0] = 1, you don't recreate an array, you just change the content of the array.

Comment: @CharlesBrunet the array will have to be created at some point. This clever one-liner just do it all in one operation.

Answer (score 8):

There are many different things you can do:

```
a=np.copy(b)
a=np.array(b) # Does exactly the same as np.copy
a[:]=b # a needs to be preallocated
a=b[np.arange(b.shape[0])]
a=copy.deepcopy(b)
```

Things that don't work

```
a=b
a=b[:] # This have given my code bugs
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not to use

```
a = 0 + b
```

I think it is similar to previous multiplication but might be simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the destination array `a` already exists, I can think of three options (two of which already mentioned in other answers):

```py
a[...] = b
a[:] = b
np.copyto(a, b)
```

I have tested them in the case of contiguous arrays. All of them are approximately equally fast for large arrays (because the time is dominated by the actual copy time, which is done equally efficiently in all three). For small arrays the first one appears to be slightly faster than the second one, which is slightly faster than the third one. In terms of readability for me the first two are roughly equivalent (with a slight preference for the first one as it does not imply a slightly confusing iteration over the first dimension of the destination matrix). I find the last one less readable as I tend to forget if it's Intel (`mov dst, src`) or AT&T (`mov src, dst`) syntax, unless one uses named arguments (`np.copyto(dst=a, src=b)`) which may be a bit verbose. It doesn't help that `copyto` has the destination first while ufuncs have it last (e.g. `np.sin(b, a)` is equivalent to `a[...] = np.sin(b)` except for avoiding the creation of a temporary array).