# Matrix related calculation in python

Tags: python-2.7, matrix

I am finding a very interesting problem while calculating a matrix update in python . I have to calculate the error  (which is difference between previous n updated matrix ).

```html
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#from matplotlib import animation 
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter



def update(A):
    C=A
    D=A
    D[1:-1,1:-1]=(C[0:-2,1:-1]+C[2:,1:-1]+C[1:-1,0:-2]+C[1:-1,2:])/4
    
    return(np.abs(D-C),D)

def error(A,B):
    C=np.zeros(np.shape(A),np.float64)
    #e=np.max(np.max(np.abs(C))) 
    e=(np.abs(C))
    return (e.sum(dtype='float64'))  

def initial(C):
    C[0,:]=0 ## Top Boundary
    C[-1,:]=0 ## Bottom Boundary
    C[:,0]=0   ## left Boundary
    C[:,-1]=100 ## Right Boundary
    return(C)


def SolveLaplace(nx, ny,epsilon,imax):
    ## Initialize the mesh with some values
    U = np.zeros((nx, ny),np.float64)
    ## Set boundary conditions for the problem
    U=initial(U)
    ## Store previous grid values to check against error tolerance
    UN=np.zeros((nx, ny),np.float64)
    UN=initial(UN)


    ## Constants
    k = 1          ## Iteration counter
    ## Iterative procedure
    
    while k<imax:
        err,U=update(U)
        print(err.sum())
        k+=1
          
   
    return (U)
            
nx = 50.0
ny = 50.0
dx = 0.001
epsilon = 1e-6 ## Absolute Error tolerance
imax = 5000    ## Maximum number of iterations allowed






Z = SolveLaplace(nx, ny,epsilon,imax)
#x = np.linspace(0, nx * dx, nx)
#y = np.linspace(0, ny * dx, ny)
#X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

##===================================================================

def PlotSolution(nx,ny,dx,T):

    ## Set up x and y vectors for meshgrid
    x = np.linspace(0, nx * dx, nx)
    y = np.linspace(0, ny * dx, ny)

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
    ax.plot_surface(X, Y, T.transpose(), rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.cool, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
    plt.xlabel("X")
    plt.ylabel("Y")
    #plt.zlabel("T(X,Y)")

    plt.figure()
    plt.contourf(X, Y, T.transpose(), 32, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.cool)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.xlabel("X")
    plt.ylabel("Y")

    plt.show()
##===================================================================


PlotSolution(nx, ny, dx, Z)
```

I am suppose to solve Laplace equation for 2-d sheet(temperature distribution) and when error is less than certain minimum value ,equilibrium will be achieved. But while calculating error, I am always getting 0 but when I print my matrix then I find it should not be a zero . Guys I think I have some conceptual problem here and So please help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you use shallow copies, i.e., only copy the reference, when assigning `C=A; D=A` in the update function. Essentially, after the construction of `D`, all three variables `A,C,D` point to the same object. Use

```
def update(A):
    C=1.0*A
    D=1.0*A
    D[1:-1,1:-1]=(C[0:-2,1:-1]+C[2:,1:-1]+C[1:-1,0:-2]+C[1:-1,2:])/4

    return(np.abs(D-C),D)
```

or even shorter

```
def update(A):
    D=A.copy()
    D[1:-1,1:-1]=(A[0:-2,1:-1]+A[2:,1:-1]+A[1:-1,0:-2]+A[1:-1,2:])/4

    return(np.abs(D-A),D)
```

Passing arguments and performing arithmetic operations results automatically in a deep copy.

---

You know that the (geometric, first order) convergence rate is something like `max(1-C/(nx^2), 1-C/(ny^2))`, i.e., very slow for even moderately large grids? For real applications, better use conjugate gradients, other Krylov-related algorithms or multi-grid approaches (or sparse solver libraries, UMFpack ...).

---

In the (unused) `error` procedure, should there be not something like

```
e = abs(A-B)
```

At the moment, you return the norm of the freshly generated zero matrix `C`.

Comment: I think `A.copy()` is a bit more explicit

Comment: Yes. I was relying on http://stackoverflow.com/a/6435446/3088138 . But avoiding arithmetic operations should be some percents faster.