# Remove row from matrix in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I've got `matrix = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` and `matrix2=matrix`. Now I want to delete first row from matrix2 i.e., `matrix2.remove(matrix[0])`.

But I am getting this

```
>>> matrix2.remove(matrix2[0])
>>> matrix2
    [[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> matrix
    [[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

First row of `matrix` is also removed. Can anyone explain this? And how to remove first row from `matrix2` without altering `matrix`

Comment: you need to make a deep copy of your matrix ... possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431973/how-to-copy-data-from-a-numpy-array-to-another

Comment: Nope @JulienSpronck. My question is "What is happening here!!??" I am removing row of matrix2, why row from matrix is also removed!?

Comment: check this other question as well ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
>>> matrix = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>>
>>> # make matrix2 a (shallow) copy of matrix
>>> matrix2 = matrix[:]
>>> matrix2.remove(matrix[0])
>>> print(matrix2)
[[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Hmm ... why is that?  Its because the statement `matrix2 = matrix` does not "copy" a value ... it merely means that the *name* `matrix2` points to the exact same value as the *name* `matrix`.

To actually create a (shallow) copy of a list, we can just slice it as `matrix2 = matrix[:]`.  This creates a *name* `matrix2` that points to a new list containing all the values of the *name* `matrix`

Answer (score 3):

You could use the copy module in the standard library:

```
from copy import deepcopy

matrix = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
matrix2 = deepcopy(matrix)

matrix2.remove(matrix2[0])

matrix
[Out]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
matrix2
[Out]: [[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 2):

List is mutable type, when you assign it with assignment operator to a different variable (`matrix2=matrix`), it just refer the same object, means two reference variable (`matrix2,matrix`) refers the same object. so in this case we need to copy the actual object by using `copy.copy()` or `copy.deepcopy()`, function and assign to the other variable. here I am using `copy.copy()`.

```
from copy import *

matrix = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] 
matrix1 = copy(matrix)    
matrix1.remove(matrix1[0])

matrix
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] 
matrix1 
[[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```