# creating a new identical numpy array that does not affect the old array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Ok before we get into the details, I have searched on site for any similar problems but most of them are not solutions that worked for me.

Here is what I tried to do:

```
my_array = np.zeros([5,5])

for i in range(4):
    temp = my_array[:]
    temp +=1
```

So I need to do a try and error on my_array without changing it. This is a simplified version with just some key points. But the trial I made changes both my_array and temp.

So far, the solutions on this web made use of [:] or .copy. I have tried both ways but it still affects my_array.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy data from a numpy array to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431973/how-to-copy-data-from-a-numpy-array-to-another)

Comment: The use of `[:]` is called slicing. If you slice an array you get a view of the original array representation. The data its refering to is still the same as before the slice. Therefor you cannot edit one without changing the other aswell. 
However `a.copy()` always creates a deep copy of your array, which allows you to edit one without modifying the other. Just do a `temp = my_array.copy()` before the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`copy` works:

```
my_array = np.zeros([5,5])

for i in range(4):
    temp = my_array.copy()
    temp +=1

print(temp)
#[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
# [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
# [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
# [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
# [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]]

print(my_array)
#[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
# [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
# [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
# [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
# [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Comment: Oh yea! I think i used it wrongly previously Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform a deepcopy

```
import copy

temp = copy.deepcopy(my_array)
```

after this any changes made to temp will not be reflected upon `my_array`

That should do it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer! I tried it and got "name 'copy' is not defined"
So I tried temp.deepcopy(my_array) and got AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'deepcopy'

Comment: You need to write temp = copy.deepcopy(my_array) not temp.deepcopy
and make sure you import copy first

Comment: Basically:

Add this line to the top of your program
"import copy" without the quotes obviously 
Then copy the array into temp using the following code

"temp = copy.deepcopy (my_array)"

If the line import copy gives an error please install that in your system.
I would suggest installing the Anaconda package